# PostgreSQL: Cannot change directory to /root

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgis

I am trying to copy a table `planet_osm_polygon` from one database `osm` to another `test`. I `su postgres` and performed the `pg_dump`.

**Problem:** However I'm getting the error `could not change directory to "/root"` and the `Password:` prompt appeared twice! Is there a way to perform the `pg_dump` when logged in as `root`?

```
root@lalaland:~# su postgres
postgres@lalaland:/root$ pg_dump -h localhost "osm" --table "public.planet_osm_polygon" | 
    psql -h localhost "test" --table "staging.planet_osm_polygon"
could not change directory to "/root"
could not change directory to "/root"
Password: Password:
```

---

### UPDATE

**Problem #2:** It appears that the table is copied into the `public` schema even though I passed the flag `--table="staging.planet_osm_polygon"`. Why isn't it copied to schema `staging`?

Comment: There is no --table parameter to `psql`, that may be the cause of problem #2

Comment: @dezso I'm using `pg_dump`, is that actually calling `psql`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: No, but your command line contains `psql -h localhost "test" --table "staging.planet_osm_polygon"`

Comment: @dezso Oh I didn't notice that!! I guess it will always be copied to `public` schema then

Comment: This issue is because pgsql/ directory does not exists, you have to create it in /var/lib/pgsql this work for me.. Kind regards
Hiram

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this: [Re: could not change directory to "/root"](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12720.1280260751@sss.pgh.pa.us):

> Apparently you did "su postgres" from the root account, so you're
>   still in root's home directory.  It'd be better to do "su - postgres"
>   to ensure you've acquired all of the postgres account's environment.
>   Reading "man su" might help you out here.

Comment: Is it normal that its asking for the password twice? Typing the password a second time does not mask it.

Comment: Maybe because you are doing two operations:

1. pg_dump -h localhost "osm" --table "public.planet_osm_polygon" 
2. psql -h localhost "test" --table "staging.planet_osm_polygon"

Comment: Alternative with sudo: sudo -Hiu postgres

Comment: Yeah, I probably should finally read over man su / sudo carefully...

Answer (score 5):

For me this did the trick, pay attention to quotes (')

```
sudo -Hiu postgres 'pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=someTable entities_db > /var/backups/anywhere/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_someTable.sql'
```

Note the `-Hiu`for sudo, or use `su - postgres`

you can also put that in a cronjob for root with `crontab -e`

Comment: great! I guess -hu would suffice, explanation here: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sudo+-Hiu

Comment: No, -H sets HOME env var and -i changes to that directory, so -iu works for me.