# postgres user cannot drop database

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to drop some databases on a postgres 9.6 server, but when I try Im told I am unable to.

I was under the impression that the `postgres` user was like a superuser.

```
su postgres
bash-4.2$ psql
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
psql (9.6.8)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> DROP DATABASE d;
ERROR:  must be owner of database d
postgres=>
```

Comment: As a superuser you can always take ownership of that database, then drop it.

Comment: hmm, superusers usally get a `=#` prompt, not `=>`.

Comment: You have a  previously abandoned question in [postgres user is not superuser](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195231/postgres-user-is-not-superuser) which seems closely related.

Comment: Yes youre right. And I think this, and the other problem are probably due to being hacked

Answer (score -1):

The problem with `su postgres` command, you changed the user to posgress but bash (to be more specific environment) owner still root or the original user, in-order to fix this issue use `su - postgres` instead of `su postgres`

Comment: with or without  `-` makes no difference to the psql command

Comment: @Jasen your reference please, that `-` will not do any side effect, here is my references
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40335/postgresql-cannot-change-directory-to-root
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782366/postgresql-cannot-change-to-root-with-u-shortcut
https://serverfault.com/questions/718176/postgres-root-permission-denied

Comment: ok, but it makes no difference to the database permissions

Comment: @Jasen your reference please

Comment: just try it, you will see.